# Google Play In app billing testing with a static response

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am following this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) for testing static subscription purchase.

[image]

But it looks like the given link **Set up test accounts** is broken. Can any one help on how to test a subscription purchase statically?

I tried the reserved product id **android.test.purchased** but then Google Play crashes which is a know issue as per this StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240471/google-play-service-stops-working-when-i-make-a-purchase-with-android-test-purch).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are willing to momentarily publish your app, one option is to install an alpha build on your phone, and then create set responses (always succeed, always fail etc) for the email of the account you installed the app with

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please tell me on how to create "set Responses"? Do I need to this at client side or at play console?

Comment: Go to your console, then settings -> developer account -> account details, then scroll down to license testing. Add your email and test response there. More details here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup